# AngularJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined in run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-service, angularfire

I am trying to route all unauthorized traffic to the login page, and am using angularfire to authenticate. [Here's all the relevant code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2C9dq0A9E2UPENiuudl?p=preview) I know most of it is broken, but I'd like to get past this first. The problematic code is:

App.js

```
 app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticatorService', function ($rootScope, $location, AuthenticatorService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {

            if (AuthenticatorService.isLoggedIn) {
                console.log('DENY');
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            else {
                console.log('ALLOW');
                $location.path('/home');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had missed couple of things in your code

1. Your `ng-app` should be `ng-app="BillingApp"` instead of `ng-app="App"`
2. You are missing `$rootScope` reference in service DI array.

**Code**

```
auth.service('AuthenticatorService', [ '$firebaseAuth', '$rootScope',//<--added this
    function($firebaseAuth,$rootScope) {
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5iOPkVAICa2vqLk3AuRY?p=preview)